# Cauchy's theorem, and Peano's theorem

Tags: calculus

We were asked to use [Cauchy's mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem) In proving the following inequallities:

1. $cosx < 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}$ for every $x \neq 0$
2. $sinx < x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120}$ for every $x>0$.

I can prove this to. But not with [Cauchy's mean value theorem.

**here is my proof for 1:**

**first proof**: by calculating few first elements of Taylor series at 0 we get:
$1 - \frac{x^2}{2} < cosx < 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}$

**left side of inequality**
i prove that $1-cosx > \frac{x^2}{2}$ by Caushy's Theorem:
Take: $f(x)=1-cosx$, $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$. by applying the theorem in the interval $[0,x]$ we get:
$\frac{1-cosx-(1-cos0)}{\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{0^2}{2}} = \frac{-sinc}{\frac{c^2}{2}}<1$.

We were also asked to prove the following equality with [Peano's for for remeinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem)

3. Let $f$ be twice diferentiable at $x$. Prove that: 
   $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x) +f(x-h)}{h^2}=f^{''}(x)$

Thanks a lot for ahyone who can help.

[image]

Comment: pay attention to the range of $x$ : $\cos(0.8)>1-((0.8)/2)+((0.8)^4/(24))$http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%280.8%29%3E1-%28%280.8%29%2F2%29%2B%28%280.8%29%5E4%2F%2824%29%29

Comment: You have a typo, it should be $\cos x < 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}$. You forgot the $^2$ on the second term.

Comment: thats true. so, any answers?

Comment: did.. is there anyone who can answer this, or is it too difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second question: Insert $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\tfrac12f''(x)h^2+\tfrac16f'''(x)h^3+r(x,h)h^4$.

Using the extended mean value theorem twice would be faster in this case.

First question: What method did you use for your known proof? You could explore the fraction

$$\frac{1-\frac{x^2}2-\cos(x)}{x^4}$$

with the ext. mean value.

---

The series for cosine

$$\cos(x)=1-\tfrac12x^2+\tfrac1{24}x^4-\tfrac1{720}x^6\pm\dots+\tfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}+\dots$$

and sine

$$\sin(x)=x-\tfrac16x^3+\tfrac1{120}x^5\mp\dots+\tfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}+\dots$$

are alternating. The Leibniz test requires monotonic decrease, which requires $x^2<(2n-1)2n$ for the cosine and $x^2<2n(2n+1)$ for sine. Then any odd number of terms give an upper bound, any partial sum with an even number of terms a lower bound (for the sine only for $x\ge 0$). One may disregard the monotonicity between the terms of the partial sums, but not between the last term and the first of the remainder.

- $\cos(x)>1-\tfrac12x^2$ for $x^2<12$
- $\cos(x)<1-\tfrac12x^2+\tfrac1{24}x^4$ for $x^2<30$
- etc.
- $\sin(x)<x$ for $x^2<6$
- $\sin(x)>x-\tfrac16x^3$ for $x^2<20$
- $\sin(x)<x-\tfrac16x^3+\tfrac1{120}x^5$ for $x^2<42$
- etc.

In the graphical representation one sees that these inequalities remain valid longer than indicated by the monotonicity conditions.

---

By the extended mean value theorem

$$\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2} = \frac{f'(x+h_1)-f(x-h_1)}{2h_1} = \frac{f''(x+h_2)+f''(x-h_2)}2$$

with $0<h_2<h_1<h$ depending on $f$, $x$ and $h$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. in the first question: i have edited above and added my solution (what do you think?). Thanks again!!

Comment: Hi, now that I look more closely, I still don't see it.. if I substitute: $x-a=h,a=x-h$, The peano formula is: $f(x)=f(x-h) + f'(x-h)h +\frac{1}{2}f''(x-h)h^2 + R$. So I get $f''(x-h)=\frac{-2f(x)-2f(x-h)-f'(x-h)h}{h^2}$. but, how do i continue from there?

Comment: In the second froof: When I use the theorem on $\frac{1-\frac{x^2}{2}-cosx-(1-\frac{0^2}{2}-cos0)}{x^4}=\frac{1-\frac{c^2}{2}+sinc}{4c^3}$. How do I continue from there?

Comment: I'll add an easier variant above.

Comment: For the second divided difference, you replace both f(x+h) and f(x-h) by expressions using f and derivatives at x.